# Append and read last line of file

Tags: python-3.x, file

Is there a way to append to a file and read it with the same "open" file command in Python3.7? I mean I do not want to have two open statements, one for open("//", "a") and one for open("//", "r"). What I am trying to achieve is run a script which appends the output to the file, and then read the last line of the file. "a+" does not help; it gives a index of out range for readlines()[-1].

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Opening the file in `a+` makes the file pointer point to the end of the file, which makes it hard to read the last line. You can instead open the file in `r+` mode, iterate over the file object until you obtain the last line, and then append the additional output to the file:

```
with open('file', 'r+') as file:
    for line in file:
        pass
    file.write(output)

# variable line now holds the last line
# and the file now has the content of output at the end
```

Comment: So the requirement is to first append the file and then read the last line. Any ideas?

Comment: Yes it can be done, but why would you want to do it in that particular order, when it would not make any difference in the end result? No matter you read the last line first or you write the output first, the end result would be that the file gets appended with extra output, and that you have the content of the last line read into a variable.

Comment: I did the up check mark actually. But reputation is less than 15, I guess that's why it's not showing up :)